# Get last article - Shopify / Liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm trying to retrieve the most recent article on a blog. My current code below does not output anything.

```
{% for article in blogs['myblog'].articles.last %}
  {{ article.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a loop in order to access the last item.

```
{% assign article = blogs['myblog'].articles.last %}
```

This will set `article` to the last item. You can then use it as expected.

```
{{ article.title }}
```

Docs: https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/filters/array-filters#last

Comment: The for loop is redundant. There's no reason to iterate over every item when there's a simple way to access the last item.

Comment: I have changed the accepted answer to the above

Answer (score 3):

It can be done like this using [forloop.last](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects/for-loops#forloop-last):

```
{% for article in blogs['myblog'].articles %}
    {% if forloop.last == true %}
         {{ article.title }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This assumes that `blogs` is a variable. Otherwise, try replacing `blogs['myblog'].articles` with `blog.articles`.